# Razor Gateway time out time

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

I am a flutter developer. i integrated Razor pay gateway to my eCommerce app but the time out for the payment is  only 60 seconds i need to minimum of 180 seconds for the payment.
can anybody help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Need to change gateway time out from 60 seconds to 180 seconds in razorpay